# R - Creating subsets of several datasets in a loop

Tags: r, loops

I have a quite big number of quite heavy datasets. I would like to extract a subset out of each of them and save it into different csv files (one for each dataset). These are the commands I would like to loop for all the files I have in the folder:

```
df <-read.csv("1985.csv",header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=TRUE,sep="\t")
df_short <- df[df$V6=="OPP", ]
write.csv(df_short, file = "OPP_1985.csv",row.names=FALSE)
rm(df)
rm(df_short)
```

This is probably a very noob question, but I am struggling to understand how to do it, so I would appreciate a lot help with this!

EDIT:

Following @SimonShine's suggestion, I have run this code and it works!

Comment: Are you sure you need to do it in R? This looks a bit like UNIX task, especially if the datasets are really big: `parallel "<{} awk -F$'\t' '($6 == \"OPP\")' > OPP_{}" ::: 1*.csv`

Comment: Well, I am quite new to this world, so doing it in R was the only way I could think about (also because I have no idea how to do that in UNIX -will check on that though. Thanks!)

Comment: That was my guess. UNIX is the bread and butter when it comes to big text data sets (hundreds of megabytes). Maybe you'll need to install the `GNU parallel` in your system for my command to work.

Comment: And `row_names` is probably supposed to be `row.names`.

Comment: I am running the code with `row.names` now. Hopefully it will work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify if you are trying to collect the subsets into one dataset, or if you are trying to make one file per subset. You refer to `OPP_1985` that appears out of scope for the code you wrote. Did you mean to refer to `df_short`?

You could start by abstracting what you want to do with one datafile into a function, e.g.:

```
extract_and_save_from_dataset <- function(csvfile) {
    df <- read.csv(csvfile, header=F, stringsAsFactors=T, sep="\t")
    df_short <- df[df$V6 == "OPP",]
    csvfile_short <- gsub(".csv", "_short.csv", csvfile)
    write.csv(df_short, file=csvfile_short, row_names=F)
}
```

Assuming you have a collection of dataset filenames, you could apply this function multiple times:

```
# csvfiles <- c("OPP_1985.csv", "OPP_1986.csv", ...)
csvfiles <- list.files("/path/to/my/csvfiles")
for (csvfile in csvfiles) {
    extract_and_save_from_dataset(csvfile)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` approach is probably the fastest option, specially if you have a large dataset. The function `fwrite{data.table}` works in parallel using many CPUS, making it extremely fast.

Here is how you can divide your original data according to subgroups defined based on the values of `df$V6` and save each subset into a separate `.csv` file.

```
library (data.table)

set(df)[, fwrite(.SD, paste0("output_", V6,".csv")), by = V6, .SDcols=names(df) ]
```

ps. The name of the files will be `output_*.csv` where * is the correspondent `V6` value.